# Suitable ML algorithm to classify hand poses based on finger flex

Tags: machine-learning

I've got a training set containing the relative flex data of four fingers (0.0 = not flexed, 1.0 = maximum flexed).

I'm looking for a suitable machine learning algorithm to classify 6 different hand poses.

Which algorithm would be suitable for this classiciation?

Comment: What sort of classification do you need?
Is this supervised or not?
Is the degree of flex your only metric?

Comment: Yes,it is supervised. I train with a dataset before classifying anything. The flex is the one metric I take into consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand so far is that you have a set of floats in the range [0.0,1.0] that you want to split into six categories.  You have given classifications for training.  This makes it a very simple problem -- although you can solve it in a number of ways.

Perhaps the simplest and most reliable is a seeded k-means algorithm: dictate starting points, one from each class, and let the algorithm run.  A more involved version of this would be a multi-class (6 classes) SVM, which takes all the training into account and finds the boundaries.

Comment: Thanks, I tried a support vector classification algorithm and am getting already good results  without altering the default configuration at all.